# Django - Store form data with changing fields

Tags: django, database, forms, model

I am trying to make a platform to handle various custom forms whose fields are are not known beforehand (similar to google forms). How can I manage the data entries from the form to my backend/ database. (django -> sql postgress)?

I thought of using the standard Django models, but they need the fields to be pre-specified in code.